# Solucion generar N*N Documents

Tags: java

Tengo un problema. Mi proyecto en spring boot recibe un JSON (mapeado a pojo con JACKSON) de opciones y un XML que llamaremos XML ORIGINAL.

Cada opcion, viene con una series de tags que se tienen que modificar sobre el XML original.

Supongamos un JSON con:

```
 Opcion 1 = N valores;
 Opcion 2 = M valores;
 Opcion 3 = K valores;
 .....
 Opcion X = R valores
```

Cada Opcion, debe generar X variaciones en base a los valores que tengo. Ej: Para el XML ORIGINAL debo generar N variaciones para la Opcion 1, la Opcion 2 debe generar M variaciones de los documentos resultantes de Opcion 1, la Opcion 3 debe generar K variaciones de los documentos resultantes de Opcion 2, la Opcion X debe generar R variaciones de los documentos resultantes de Opcion 3.

En sintesis, me debe dar variaciones de `NxMxKxR` XML ORIGINALES.

Siguiendo mi algoritmo,obtengo el siguiente error:

> 2018-12-04 11:37:55.125 WARN 7296 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=49s823ms348µs491ns)

Mi variacion se genera de la siguiente forma:

```
    package com.example.restproyect.states;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.concurrent.Future;

    import javax.persistence.Transient;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import com.example.restproyect.Documento;
    import com.example.restproyect.filtros.FiltroAbs;
    import com.example.restproyect.filtros.FiltroNombre;
    import com.example.restproyect.hilos.Tarea;
    import com.example.restproyect.hilos.TareaRastrojo;
    import com.example.restproyect.states.objetosinternos.Pastura;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({ "digestibilidadVariaciones", "rindeVariaciones" })
    public class Rastrojo implements Serializable{

        @JsonProperty("digestibilidadVariaciones")
        private List<Pastura> digestibilidadVariaciones = null;

        @JsonProperty("rindeVariaciones")
        private List<Pastura> rindeVariaciones = null;

        @Transient
        private FiltroAbs filtro = new FiltroNombre("crop_stubbles");

        @JsonIgnore
        private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
            return this.additionalProperties;
        }

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
            this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        }



        public List<Pastura> getDigestibilidadVariaciones() {
            return digestibilidadVariaciones;
        }

        public void setDigestibilidadVariaciones(List<Pastura> digestibilidadVariaciones) {
            this.digestibilidadVariaciones = digestibilidadVariaciones;
        }

        public List<Pastura> getRindeVariaciones() {
            return rindeVariaciones;
        }

        public void setRindeVariaciones(List<Pastura> rindeVariaciones) {
            this.rindeVariaciones = rindeVariaciones;
        }

        public void setAdditionalProperties(Map<String, Object> additionalProperties) {
            this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Rastrojo [digestibilidadVariaciones=" + digestibilidadVariaciones + ", rindeVariaciones="
                    + rindeVariaciones + ", additionalProperties=" + additionalProperties + "]"+"\n";
        }

        public static ArrayList<Pastura> cloneList( List<Pastura> list) {
             ArrayList<Pastura> clone = new ArrayList<Pastura>(list.size());
            for (Pastura item : list) 
                clone.add(item.clone());
            return clone;
        }

        public Hashtable<Integer, Documento> generarEscenarios(Hashtable<Integer, Documento> escenarios) {
            Hashtable<Integer, Documento> newEscenarios = new Hashtable<Integer, Documento>();
            //Numero de threads
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
            ArrayList<Future<ArrayList<Documento>>> listFuture = new ArrayList<>();
            //Por cada escenario que entre. Los escenarios arrancan en 1
            for(int indexEscenarios = 0; indexEscenarios < escenarios.size(); indexEscenarios++) {
                //Generar para ese escenario, la variacion correspondiente
                listFuture.add(executor.submit(new TareaRastrojo(
                                                cloneList(digestibilidadVariaciones), 
                                                cloneList(rindeVariaciones), filtro,escenarios.get(indexEscenarios), indexEscenarios)));

            }       
            while(!executor.isTerminated()) {

            }       
            int count = 1;
            for(Future<ArrayList<Documento>> resultado:listFuture){
                if(resultado.isDone()){
                    try {
                        for(Documento doc:resultado.get()) {
                            System.out.println("---------------------------AGREGANDO ESCENARIO["+count+"]---------------------------------------");
                            count++;
                            //newEscenarios.put(newEscenarios.size(), doc);
                        }
                        //System.out.println("-------CANTIDAD DE ESCENARIOS------["+newEscenarios.size()+"]");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }             
            }                       

            System.out.println("-------CANTIDAD DE ESCENARIOS------");
            System.out.println("-------CANTIDAD DE ESCENARIOS------["+newEscenarios.size()+"]");
            return newEscenarios;
        }





    }

Cada TareaRastrojo es un Objeto que se comporta asi:

package com.example.restproyect.hilos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.example.restproyect.Documento;
import com.example.restproyect.filtros.FiltroAbs;
import com.example.restproyect.states.objetosinternos.Pastura;

    public class TareaRastrojo implements Callable<ArrayList<Documento>>{

        private ArrayList<Pastura> digestibilidadVariaciones;
        private ArrayList<Pastura> rindeVariaciones;
        private FiltroAbs filtro;
        private Documento doc;
        private int numero;



        public TareaRastrojo(ArrayList<Pastura> digestibilidadVariaciones, ArrayList<Pastura> rindeVariaciones, FiltroAbs filtro,
                Documento doc, int numero) {
            super();
            this.digestibilidadVariaciones = digestibilidadVariaciones;
            this.rindeVariaciones = rindeVariaciones;
            this.filtro = filtro;
            this.doc = doc;
            this.numero = numero;
        }



        public ArrayList<Documento> call() {    
            ArrayList<Documento> documentosGenerados = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("***************************************************************************************");
            System.out.println("Documento numero ="+this.numero);
            for(int indexVariaciones = 0; indexVariaciones < digestibilidadVariaciones.get(0).getPasturas().size(); indexVariaciones++) {
                Document newDocument = this.doc.getDocumento();         
                System.out.println("Variacion numero["+indexVariaciones+"] de la tarea numero ["+this.numero+"]");
                Documento doc = new Documento(newDocument);         
                Document insertDoc = doc.clonarDocumento();
                newDocument = null;

                doc.setDocumento(insertDoc);

                //Para cada tag dentro del tag <escenario> Busco los tags que tienen las variaciones
                NodeList node = doc.getDocumento().getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes();     
                for(int j=0; j < node.getLength(); j++) {
                    /*
                     * indice par es un text dentro de los tags, solo 
                     * se trabaja con los elementos impares
                     * que son los TAGS
                     */
                    if(j%2 != 0) {

                            Node nodo =  node.item(j);
                            if(filtro.cumple(nodo)) {
                                //Obtengo la pastura a variar                               
                                NodeList nodePastura = node.item(j).getChildNodes();                        

                                for(int indexPastura = 0; indexPastura < digestibilidadVariaciones.size(); indexPastura++) {                
                                    //Formula para obtener la pastura que va a variar
                                    System.out.println("Variacion numero["+indexVariaciones+"] de la tarea numero ["+this.numero+"] de la PASTURA ["+indexPastura+"]");
                                    Node nodoPastura = nodePastura.item(indexPastura*2+1);  
                                    nodoPastura.getAttributes().getNamedItem("crop_stubbleDigest").setNodeValue(String.valueOf(digestibilidadVariaciones.get(indexPastura).next()));
                                    nodoPastura.getAttributes().getNamedItem("yield").setNodeValue(String.valueOf(rindeVariaciones.get(indexPastura).next()));
                                    System.out.println("FIN DE LA Variacion numero["+indexVariaciones+"] de la tarea numero ["+this.numero+"] de la PASTURA ["+indexPastura+"]");
                                }   
                                System.err.print("FIN DE LA Variacion numero["+indexVariaciones+"] de la tarea numero ["+this.numero+"]");
                                documentosGenerados.add(doc);

                            }       
                    }                   

                }
            }
            for(int indexPastura = 0; indexPastura < digestibilidadVariaciones.size(); indexPastura++) {                                
                digestibilidadVariaciones.get(indexPastura).resetUltimaSeleccion();
                rindeVariaciones.get(indexPastura).resetUltimaSeleccion();
            }
            System.err.println("Finalizando Documento numero ="+this.numero);
            System.out.println("***************************************************************************************");
            return documentosGenerados;         

        }




    }


    package com.example.restproyect.states.objetosinternos;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({ "pasturas" })
    public class Pastura implements Serializable,Cloneable{

        @JsonProperty("pastura")
        private List<Integer> pasturas = null;

        private int ultimaSeleccion = 0; 

        @JsonIgnore
        private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();


        public Pastura(ArrayList<Integer> pasturas) {
            super();
            this.pasturas = pasturas;
        }

        public Pastura(List<Integer> pasturas, Map<String, Object> additionalProperties) {
            super();
            this.pasturas = pasturas;
            this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
            return this.additionalProperties;
        }

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
            this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        }

        public List<Integer> getPasturas() {
            return pasturas;
        }

        public void setPasturas(List<Integer> pasturas) {
            this.pasturas = pasturas;
        }

        public void setAdditionalProperties(Map<String, Object> additionalProperties) {
            this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
        }


        public float next() {
            float valor = this.pasturas.get(this.ultimaSeleccion);
            this.ultimaSeleccion = this.ultimaSeleccion + 1;
            return valor;
        }



        public void resetUltimaSeleccion() {
            this.ultimaSeleccion = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pastura [pasturas=" + pasturas + ", additionalProperties=" + additionalProperties + "]";
        }

        public Pastura clone(){
            return new Pastura(new ArrayList<Integer>(this.pasturas)); //new ArrayList<Integer>(this.pasturas);
        }
    }
```

El context switching de los hilos funcionan bien, donde puedo ver como los mensajes aparecen en desorden

El problema es que el CPU se va al 100% y no finaliza su ejecucion faltando 500 escenarios por generar.

Cabe destacar que estoy probando generar 5^5 documentos = 3125 y los genera bien pero al generar el siguiente nivel que daria 5^6 = 15625 en la generacion del escenario 11000 al 12000 se clava el CPU. No finaliza en el mismo escenario sino que va variando. Alguna idea de porque puede quedar colgado?

CPU al 100%

Answer (score 0):

Este loop debería estar disparándote la cpu:

```
    while(!executor.isTerminated()) {

    }
```

Fijate de usar `taskExecutor.awaitTermination(..)` o al menos ponele un `Thread.sleep(2000)` para que libere la cpu.

Por otro lado también podés explorar la opción ponerle un tope de threads concurrentes al executor.